# Android TextView

Tags: android, textview, tablelayout

I have created `tablelayout` and in that `tablelayout` m adding row dynamically. at the same time m adding four `TextView` in rows dynamically. the `TextView` size varies. my question is how to set height of a `TextView` accordingly. i.e if size of one `TextView` increases accordingly adjust that particular row height. Please help me.

Comment: In my xml i have set tablelayout background as gray. so that every row should visible precisely.

Answer (score 0):

the following few steps might help u.

1) set the table row width as fill_parent & height as wrap_content.
2) add these four textview in order in which u want to display on ui.

e.g

```
tablerow.addview(textView1,LayoutParams.wrap_content,LayoutParams.wrap_content);
  tablerow.addview(textView2,LayoutParams.wrap_content,LayoutParams.wrap_content);
  tablerow.addview(textView3,LayoutParams.wrap_content,LayoutParams.wrap_content);
  tablerow.addview(textView4,LayoutParams.wrap_content,LayoutParams.wrap_content);
```

& finally

```
table.addView(tablerow,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.wrap_content));
```

Comment: @ Vladimir&Sumant:I have already tried this but its not working.